# Hide fields if it is empty

Tags: php, mysql, is-empty, notnull

I am using this code, I want to just those field there is no empty if any fields is empty then not open the image from my sql server,

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM movie_post WHERE id=$id AND NOT IS NULL(linkfrom2,m_link2,linkfrom3,m_link3,linkfrom4,m_link4,linkfrom5,m_link5)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movie_post WHERE id=$id AND linkfrom2 IS NOT NULL AND  m_link2 IS NOT NULL AND linkfrom3 IS NOT NULL AND m_link3 IS NOT NULL AND linkfrom4 IS NOT NULL AND m_link4 IS NOT NULL AND linkfrom5 IS NOT NULL AND m_link5 IS NOT NULL";
```

I do not know a shorter way to write this statement.